# IBM MobileFirst issue with securityTest="wl_unprotected" in IBM Containers

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst

My adapter is running in an IBM Container. I have marked all my procedures as securityTest="wl_unprotected".

Everything works fine locally when testing with browser simulation, but fails when I try the same after deploying both the app and adapter in container.

I do get my first page pulling data correctly, but subsequent calls for navigating to other pages of the application fail. All I see is following error messge

> http://134.168.16.88:9080/MobileFirstStarter/authorization/v1/clients/preview?applicationId=econfig_poc_mf&applicationVersion=1.0&environment=common&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.06548149750907506

With status as "404 Not Found"

I am not sure why this is failing in a container but working fine locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an external server environment there is no preview available - the servlet that allows previewing of an application is not present, which is *expected*.

Previewing applications is available only in the development environment, locally.

If you'd like to preview your application once moving to an external server environment (QA, UAT, Production... bluemix or not), you'll need to test it in a device. Alternatively you could add the Mobile Web or Desktop Browser environments as well, which will allow previewing in the browser (but of course may not have all capabilities available to a Mobile app).

Comment: thanks for explaination, I am very new to mobile and that to mobile-first world, I will aprpeciate if you can elaborate on how to add 
 "add the Mobile Web or Desktop Browser environments" Will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In MobileFirst Studio in Eclipse, where you first created your project, right-click your project folder and select New -> MobileFirst Environment. Please read the tutorials on the Developer Center to learn more: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform. You will then also need to re-deploy your project back to the IBM Container.

Comment: I am getting following errors when using Mobile Web/Desktop browser
                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0037E: Browser request exception:  [project tetst]
Invalid gadget request format: /xxx/mobilewebapp/adapters/econfigAdapter/getXXX. Unknown handler path: adapters